# Can't use 'put'() to add data to hbase with happybase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, python-3.7, happybase

My python version is 3.7, and after I ran `pip3 install happybase`, I started the command `hbase thrift start` and tried to write a brief .py file as following:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('master')
table = connection.table('jmlr')   #'jmlr' is a table in hbase
for i in table.scan():
        print(i)
table.put('001', {'title':'dasds'})   #error here
connection.close()
```

When it's about to run `table.put()`, it reported such an error:

`thriftpy2.transport.base.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')`

And at the same time, the `thrift` reported an error:

`ERROR [thrift-worker-1] thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid famAndQf provided.`

But just now I ran this python file again, it gave me a different error in `thrift`:

`thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer: Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Bad version in readMessageBegin`

I have tried to add parameters like `protocol='compact', transport='framed'`, but this didn't work, even the `table.scan()` failed.
Everything in the `hbase shell` is OK, so I can't figure out what went wrong, I'm about to collapse.

Comment: By the way, I run this file on the master host, is something needed to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found this sollution. You need to add even empty Column Qualifier ( ':' symbol as delimiter between Column Family and Column Qualifier) into put() method:

```
table.put('001:', {'title':'dasds'})
```

Also, you have a different error message after second run of script because thrift server is already failed.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your comment, although my code has been fixed with `md5(item['title'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`.  it's a queer problem, I have tried to use `encode()`but it. just doesn't work like above, maybe something is different between `encode()` and `hexdigest()`.  anyhow, thanks a lot!